# Linux date format hh-mm-ss

Tags: linux, bash, date

I got a problem if the time is before 10, because then the output is like `8-33-21` instead of `08-33-21`. My date syntax is `date +"%k-%M-%S`. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: What kept you from reading the man page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `%k`format is space padded

From the man page

> `%H` hour (00..23)
>
> `%I` hour (01..12)

As fedorqui pointed out, `%T` is the same as `%H:%M:%S`

Answer (score 4):

Use the `%H` format:

```
date +"%H-%M-%S"
```